# PHP - preg_replace not matching multiple occurrences

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Trying to replace a string, but it seems to only match the first occurrence, and if I have another occurrence it doesn't match anything, so I think I need to add some sort of end delimiter?

My code:

```
$mappings = array(
    'fname'     => $prospect->forename,
    'lname'     => $prospect->surname,
    'cname'     => $prospect->company,
);

foreach($mappings as $key => $mapping) if(empty($mapping)) $mappings[$key] = '$2';

$match  = '~{(.*)}(.*?){/.*}$~ise';
$source     = 'Hello {fname}Default{/fname} {lname}Last{/lname}';
// $source  = 'Hello {fname}Default{/fname}';

$text = preg_replace($match, '$mappings["$1"]', $source);
```

So if I use the $source that's commented, it matches fine, but if I use the one currently in the code above where there's 2 matches, it doesn't match anything and I get an error:

```
Message: Undefined index: fname}Default{/fname} {lname

Filename: schedule.php(62) : regexp code
```

So am I right in saying I need to provide an end delimiter or something?

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: You are using `.*?` in between, but left the other matches `.*` greedy. (Tip: always constrain the pattern, if there are obvious characters to allow or disallow.)

Comment: Thanks mario - Missed that one out. Any ideas on the main problem? :)

Comment: Personally, I would use [`{([^}]+)}(.*?){/\1}`](http://rubular.com/r/6HCgvUKIB7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your regexp matches `fname}Default{/fname} {lname` instead of `Default`.

As I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824436/i-want-to-add-a-referral-link-to-the-url-using-preg-replace/12824580#12824580) use `{(.*?)}` instead of `{(.*)}`.

`{` has special meaning in regexps so you should escape it `\\{`.

And I recommend using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead of `e` modifier (you have more flow control and syntax higlighting and it's impossible to force your program to execute malicious code).

Last mistake you're making is not checking whether the requested index exists. :)

My solution would be:

```
<?php

class A { // Of course with better class name :)
    public $mappings = array(
        'fname' => 'Tested'
    );

    public function callback( $match)
    {
        if( isset( $this->mappings[$match[1]])){
            return $this->mappings[$match[1]];
        }

        return $match[2];
    }   
}

$a = new A();
$match  = '~\\{([^}]+)\\}(.*?)\\{/\\1\\}~is';
$source     = 'Hello {fname}Default{/fname} {lname}Last{/lname}';

echo preg_replace_callback( $match, array($a, 'callback'), $source);
```

This results into:

```
[vyktor@grepfruit tmp]$ php stack.php
Hello Tested Last
```

Comment: You'd also have to make the last `.*` not greedy and remove the end of string anchor `$` to make it work. Also, there's no need to escape `{` here.

Comment: Brilliant - Thanks for your help guys, working :) - I've gone with @NullUserException's expression, but your implementation. Thanks again!

Comment: @christian.thomas It's the same expression, except this one has escapes everywhere. Some people like to play it safe and escape everything; I prefer escaping as little as possible for better readability.

Comment: Yep - Noted. Just looked a lot cleaner as well.

Comment: @NullUserException I'm escaping like a hamster on coffin just in PHP... Somehow I don't believe they won't change meaning of certain characters in time :-/

Comment: @Vyktor PHP's regexes follow PCRE syntax, which I doubt will change...  ever.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is anchored to the end of the string so you closing `{/whatever}` **must** be the last thing in your string.  Also, since your open and closing tags are simply `.*`, there's nothing in there to make sure they match up.  What you want is to make sure that your closing tag matches your opening one - using a backreference like `{(.+)}(.*?){/\1}` will make sure they're the same.

I'm sure there's other gotchas in there - if you have control over the format of strings you're working with (IE - you're rolling your own templating language), I'd seriously consider moving to a simpler, easier to match format.  Since you're not 'saving' the default values, having enclosing tags provides you with no added value but makes the parsing more complicated.  Just using `$VARNAME` would work just as well and be easier to match (`\$[A-Z]+`), without involving back-references or having to explicitly state you're using non-greedy matching.

Comment: @christian.thomas Regular expressions are an amazingly powerful tool.  The most important thing to learn about them is when **not** to use them - using a simpler tag syntax would allow you to just user str_replace() and not even bother with regular expressions.